# How to make gksudo or gksu sessions last longer in Linux

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, timeout, gksu

Every time I want to open a GUI program that needs root permissions, I have to put my password. For example, I open synaptic and put my password then close it and a second later decide to reopen it it asks for the password again. Ubuntu 9.04 wasn't like that, it had a timeout of around 1 minute between sessions. I would like that again on the newer version of Linux.

I know how to make `sudo` sessions last longer in Linux. All I have to do is type:

```
sudo visudo
```

then change:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

to (3 minutes):

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=3
```

Is there  a similar way to change the `gksu` session's timemouts?

Comment: tell us what distribution and what distribution version you're on. this change was probably caused by the move to polkit. `gksudo` and `gksu` are now deprecated and strongly discouraged.

Comment: I'm on linux mint 16. What's the new replacement for them and why are they depricated?

Comment: I'd take a look at this page: http://cyclopath.org/wiki/Install_Notes/Linux_Mint_16.

Comment: Also isn't `timestamp_timeout=` minutes, not seconds? http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/change-sudo-password-timeout-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/, here too: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi `gksudo` and `gksu` are deprecated due to the fact that they are extremely hacky. the proper, modern replacement for them is polkit (formerly PolicyKit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, `gksu` and `gksudo` were considered hacks and are now deprecated. Their modern counterpart is called polkit. It is a FreeDesktop.org project; you may read about it [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/).

Unfortunately, from my cursory searching (and subsequent reading of [this mailing list thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/polkit-devel@lists.freedesktop.org/msg00154.html)), it seems that what you want to do is impossible with polkit.